# Why NullReferenceException is not being caught?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a generic Catch(Exception ex) block in method. So why it is not catching that NullReferenceException exception ? This happens just once in a while.

```
public bool ChangeOrder(string conumber, string recepitnumber, string webServiceURL, string username, string password,ref string error)
{
    error = "";
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        MovexAPI objMovexAPI = new MovexAPI();
        objMovexAPI.APIName = "ZOI100MI";
        objMovexAPI.TransactionName = "ChgHead";             
        objMovexAPI.URL = webServiceURL; 
        objMovexAPI.MaxRecords = 0;
        objMovexAPI.InputKeyValuePair = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        objMovexAPI.ReturnColumns = new List<string>();

        string url = objMovexAPI.URL + objMovexAPI.APIName + "/" + objMovexAPI.TransactionName;
        string returncols = string.Join(",", objMovexAPI.ReturnColumns.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray());
        string maxrecords = objMovexAPI.MaxRecords.ToString();
        string inputValues = "";

        objMovexAPI.InputKeyValuePair.Add("CONO", "100");
        objMovexAPI.InputKeyValuePair.Add("ORNO", conumber);
        objMovexAPI.InputKeyValuePair.Add("OREF", recepitnumber);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in objMovexAPI.InputKeyValuePair)
        {
            inputValues += kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value + "&";  //"?CONO=100&FACF=H01&FACT=H01&STSF=20&STST=90";
        }
        if (inputValues.Length > 0)
        {
            inputValues = inputValues.Substring(0, inputValues.Length - 1);
        }

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url + "?" + inputValues) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        // Get response  
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        error = ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusDescription;
        result = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Shouldn't this catch all exceptions ???
    {
        error = ex.Message;
        result = false;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Exception stack trace is as below which clearly indicates that NullReferenceException occurred in the above method. Why is it not being caught by Exception ex ?

```
Exception type: NullReferenceException

Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at StaffSales.M3.OutboundData.ChangeOrder(String conumber, String recepitnumber, String webServiceURL, String username, String password, String& error)

at StaffSales.BL.CustomerOrder.ApproveCOLines(String conumber, String recepitNo, String divi, String webServiceURL, String username, String password, List`1& APIErrors)
at StaffSales.Controllers.HomeController.ProcessPayment(COPaymentModel objModel)
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this? In a log? It's possible to log exceptions even though they are handled.

Comment: Could this line be causing it? `error =  ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusDescription;`

Comment: @rob I am seeing this in Windows Event Log on the sever. It was raised as an issue by user so I am investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code could be a possible issue;

```
error = ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusDescription;
```

According to MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx

**WebException.Response Property**

Property Value
Type: System.Net.WebResponse
If a response is available from the Internet resource, a WebResponse instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource; otherwise, null.

That means you need to check for nulls.

```
 if(wex.Response != null)
 {
     error = ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusDescription;
 }
```

Comment: This could be it. Thank you for pointing it out. My understanding was if  anything withing catch failed that would have been handled by catch(Exception ex) block but that does not seems to be the case.